# Return more than One Intent from Second Activity to Main Aactivity

Tags: java, android

i'm useing `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity` and i want to send data back form `SecondActivity` to `MainActivity` but in `SecondActivity` i have two different function with two different `webservice` how can i do this.

this is in `MainActivity`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        // form Theaudiodb.com
    Glide.with(this).load(data.getStringExtra("artistThumb")).into(headerImageView);

        //from onemusic.com
       biographyAliases.setText(data.getStringExtra("aliases"));
    }

}
```

This is `SecondActivity`

```
 void parsAndSendTheAudiDbBiography(String response) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TheaudiodbBiography theaudiodbBiography = gson.fromJson(response, TheaudiodbBiography.class);

        returnIntent.putExtra("artistThumb", checkNullable(theaudiodbBiography.getArtists()
                .get(0).getStrArtistThumb()));


        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

 void parseAndShowOneMusicBio(String response) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        OneMusicBiography[] oneMusicBio = gson.fromJson(response, OneMusicBiography[].class);

        Intent returnIntent= new Intent(DialogActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        returnIntent.putExtra("aliases", oneMusicBio[0].getAliases().toString());


        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you cann't return two intent's from second activity . If you want u can pass the two methods outputs u can save in class level and return to Main Activity.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not do this.

But you can put semafor in tour second activity - and start intent to first activity after 2 calls are finished, and you can put 2 extras in it.

Or you could/should store results in DB, and send to first activity DB records id's.

something like this:

```
//we can set it to 2 as we know that there are 2 calls
    private int semafor = 2;
    private Intent returnIntent= new Intent(DialogActivity.this, MainActivity.class);


void parsAndSendTheAudiDbBiography(String response) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TheaudiodbBiography theaudiodbBiography = gson.fromJson(response, TheaudiodbBiography.class);

        returnIntent.putExtra("artistThumb", checkNullable(theaudiodbBiography.getArtists()
                .get(0).getStrArtistThumb()));
        semafor --;
        if (semafor == 0) {
            finish();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

 void parseAndShowOneMusicBio(String response) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        OneMusicBiography[] oneMusicBio = gson.fromJson(response, OneMusicBiography[].class);

        returnIntent.putExtra("aliases", oneMusicBio[0].getAliases().toString());

        semafor --;
        if (semafor == 0) {
            finish();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```